# Unit Test functions which include user input, while loops and whose input is another functions output - Python

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, while-loop, user-input

I have made a program for an ATM machine, which checks the pin that a user inputs, allows the user to enter an amount to withdraw if the pin matches and then withdraws the money from the account_balance. However, each function is seemingly dependent: the return of one function is the parameter of another. This is confusing to test each function separately and when I try to do so, the whole program runs and asks for input from each function.
As my get_pin and get_amount function also have while loops with user input, I feel like this has added another complication to the way I need to unit test.

Is there a way to do this?
Or do you think it is best to refactor my code to remove user input and while loops and just have parameters in each individual function?

The test I would like to check would be:

- withdraw_cash function - to check if the correct amount is withdrawn
- get_pin function - check if the pin matches
- get_amount function - check incorrect amount is added bringing up an error message.

My atm program is:

```
user = {
    'pin': 1234
}

def withdraw_cash(amount):
    balance_account = 100
    if amount > balance_account:
        raise ValueError("You don't have sufficient balance to make this withdrawal")
    else:
        new_balance = balance_account - amount
        return new_balance
    
    
def get_pin():
    count = 0
    to_exit = False
    while (count < 3) and (not to_exit):
        try:
            pin = int(input('Please enter your four digit pin: '))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter correct pin")
            count += 1
        if pin != user['pin']:
            print("Pin does not match.. Try Again")
            count += 1
        else:
            return get_amount(pin)        
    if count == 3:
        a = '3 UNSUCCESFUL PIN ATTEMPTS, EXITING \n !!!!!YOUR CARD HAS BEEN LOCKED!!!!!'
        return a 
            


def get_amount(pin):
    while True:
        try:
            amount = int(input("Enter the amount of money you want to withdraw: "))
        except ValueError as v:
            print(f"Enter correct amount: ")
        else:
            return withdraw_cash(amount)

try:
    get_pin()
except ValueError as v:
    print(f"ERROR: {v}")
```

Comment: You should segregate reading input and actual logic. In this case, that code is not unit testable.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Would this mean only unit testing the withdraw_cash function and the get_pin and get_amount function as the functions that read input. So not including those functions at all?

Comment: I would go with another solution. 
Keep in mind. If you struggle while writing unit testing, it means high possibility there is a violation with any of OOP paradigm or principle.
Here in the scenario, there is a violation with SR. You can write a method which does not take any argument, reads from console, and returns the string. After that, you can mock it and provide return value.

Comment: I am so sorry, I still do not understand